# Regarding Transmission and receiving Acknowledgement in UnetStack MAC layer

Tags: unetstack

Implementing Acknowledgement mechanisms in unetstack

Kindly provide information of implementing transmission/receiving of acknowledgement in MAC layer using UnetStack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easy to transmit ACK frames using the `TxFrameReq` messages sent to the `Physical` service, and receive them on the other side by subscribing to the `Physical` service and looking for `RxFrameNtf` messages. You'd want to use `Protocol.MAC` as your protocol number, so you can filter messages intended for MAC by protocol number.

An example of this is in the [MAC tutorial](https://www.unetstack.net/mac.html) (see section on "Simple MAC with handshake").

Good luck with your implementation!